# Why will the output be 11032? Python3.6

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

```
d = {10:"x", 1:"wx", 2:"yz"}
a = d.setdefault(1)
b = d.setdefault(3)
s = "{}" * len(d)
print(s.format(*d))
```

Why will the output be 11032?

Comment: Which part confuse you? Anyway I got `10123`.

Comment: But why did I get 11032? I'm using python-3.6.3. It seems that different IDE gets different results.

Comment: Python dict's keys order varies across implementations. It may depend on your platform/system. I only tested on my mac and some linux.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 setdefault calls,

```
d = {10: "x", 1: "wx", 2: "yz"}
d.setdefault(1)  # does not change the dictionary because there's already 1
d.setdefault(3)  # add 3 with value None (default if not speicfied)
```

`d` becomes:

```
>>> d
{10: 'x', 1: 'wx', 2: 'yz', 3: None}
```

Iterating dictionary yields dictionary keys: `10, 1, 2, 3`. (iteration performed by `*d` to unpack the argument `d`):

```
>>> for key in d:
...     print(key)
... 
10
1
2
3
```

So, `s.format(*d)` is equivalent to `'{}{}{}{}'.format(10, 1, 2, 3)`.